# max function in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i want receive max parentID in menu table with linq. i use this code:

```
var orderMenu = (from M in conn.Menus.ToList()
                                    where M.ParentID == _type
                                    select M.ParentID).Max();
```

but display error:

```
Sequence contains no elements
```

(The table may be empty)

Comment: What are you having problems with? If the query returns no records what do you expect `Max` to do?

Comment: try `OrderByDescending` and select `firstordefault`

Comment: What you want to achieve? Why you filter by `ParentID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return say, the max, or zero if nothing exists in the collection, you probably want to use `DefaultIfEmpty()` coupled with `Max()`

```
var orderMenu = (from M in conn.Menus.ToList()
                                select M.ParentID).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();
```

Answer (score 6):

The query is completely redundant.

You are asking for all elements where `M.ParentID == _type`, so `Max` will either be nothing (an error as observed) or `_type`, depending on whether or not such an element exists.